# jQuery .remove(Selector) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Look at this snippet:

```
var div = $('#createDrugForm');

div.remove('input[type=hidden]');
//the hidden field is still there

div.find('input[type=hidden]').remove();
//the hidden was removed
```

Why does the first method of removal not work?

Comment: the remove function accepts a string not a selector as input

Comment: read this document https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Selector `remove` method takes, is used in `filter` internally, not `find`.

Comment: According to the [API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/#remove-selector) the remove function accepts a string that's a **selector**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you provide a selector to [`$.fn.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method, this selector is used to filter already selected collection (see [`$.fn.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)), but not to find new child elements (see [`$.fn.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)).

For example, if you have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="div a">a</div>
<div class="div b">b</div>
<div class="div c">c</div>
```

you can remove `.a` div with this code

```
$('.div').remove('.a');
```

In your case you need to use `find` method and then remove found inputs.